# Decomposition of elements in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Prove that for all $\tau\in S_n$, there exist $\alpha, \beta\in S_n$, satisfying $\tau=\alpha\beta$ and $\alpha^2=\beta^2=1$. Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group.

My idea is that we need to focus on permutations whose order is $2$. And We have that $\{(1,2), (1,3), \cdots, (1,n)\}$ generates $S_n$. So $\tau$ must be product of some of them. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I would prove it for $\tau$ a $k$-cycle in $S_k$ and then deduce the general result as a corollaty. [That is, I'd be thinking of $\tau$ as a product of disjoint cycles as opposed to your way of thinking of $\tau$ as a product of transpositions.]

Comment: Examples that explain everything: $$(123456)=(16)(25)(34)\cdot(26)(35)$$ and $$(1234567)=(17)(26)(35)\cdot(27)(36)(45).$$